# Is it possible to reference microsoft.xna.framework.dll in Windows Phone 8.1 applications?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-8, xna

I want to use `MediaLibrary` class from `microsoft.xna.framework.dll` assembly in my Windows Phone application, but I am only able to do it in Silverlight applications, but not in the regular Windows Phone ones.
Is it possible to somehow reference this assembly from usual Windows Phone application? If not, why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is possible, see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff842408.aspx